# GetBackgroundBufferInfo function in Bada

Tags: bada

i want to create a bada application that taking photos and editing it.

I Created a form which should show the camera . in the onInitializing function. I do it as follow

```
result
CameraForm::OnInitializing(void)
{

    result r = E_SUCCESS;
    Osp::Graphics::BufferInfo bufferInfo;
    panel_ = static_cast<Osp::Ui::Controls::OverlayPanel*>(GetControl(L"IDC_PANEL1"));
    AppLog("before getBackgroundBufferInfo");
    panel_->GetBackgroundBufferInfo(bufferInfo);
    AppLog("done getBackgroundBufferInfo");

    camera_ = new Camera;
    camera_->Construct(*this,CAMERA_PRIMARY);
    camera_->PowerOn();
    camera_->StartPreview(&bufferInfo,true);
    return r;
}
```

the words before getBackgroundBufferInfo is shown in the console
but the don getBackgroundBufferInfo is not. What's wrong with the GetBackgroundBufferInfo function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check console for logs. It will show error there what kind of exception GetBackgroundBufferInfo(bufferInfo) throws.